# Standard Scaling not resulting in good nn inputs

Tags: neural-network, feature-scaling

I am using standard scaling to transform my dataset for input to a NN.  The normalized dataset is in the range +-0.04.  I am getting different results in the NN when simply multiplying by a factor of 20 to bring the inputs more to the range +-1 vs +-0.04.

Why am I getting different results? I thought NNs were able to handle this.

And why isn't standard scaling bringing the range to +-1?

Comment: How are you scaling the dataset? It shouldn't end up with such a narrow range.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your NN architecture and how you're doing initialization (including any random seeds ;), it's not surprising that you would get slightly different results when scaling your inputs. It's always a good idea to plot your data distribution and understand the feature ranges and distributions, and try to get these "close" to Gaussian distributions where possible, for example by replacing a feature that follows a power distribution with its log.[image]

If you're using StandardScaler from scikit-learn, it subtracts the mean and divides by the std dev so that the results have a zero mean and a standard deviation of 1.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

std_scaler = StandardScaler()
data_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(raw_data)
```

Another option is min-max scaling, which simply subtracts the min and divides by the difference max-min.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(raw_data)
```